# Pretty URL with add_query_var

Tags: posts, permalinks, url-rewriting

I'm trying to add a 'sub post' to each post on my site, eg

site.com/product-one/changelog
site.com/product-two/changelog
site.com/product-three/changelog

This is the code I'm using atm, which I found here somewhere:

```
global $wp,$wp_rewrite;
$wp->add_query_var('sub-page');
$wp_rewrite->add_rule('([^/]+)/(changelog)','index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&sub-page=$matches[2]', 'top');
$wp_rewrite->flush_rules(false);  // This should really be done in a plugin activation
```

This works fine if I browse to site.com/product-one?sub-page=changelog but if I goto site.com/product-one/changelog i just get redirected back to site.com/product-one

So I disabled the canonical redirect as a test using:

```
remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```

site.com/product-one/changelog then doesn't redirect but does return a 404 and site.com/product-one?sub-page=changelog still works.

Is there something I can change with my rewrite to make this work?

Note: I know I could do this easy with custom post types and I started to go down that route, but because the site is already using the %postname% permalink structure, I then wouldn't be able to have the custom post type have that structure as well as the sites pages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
add_rewrite_endpoint( 'changelog', EP_ROOT );
```

Will add the endpoint, `changelog`, which you can then check on `template_redirect` hook.

On match the query variables ( `$wp_query->query` ) array should contain key `changelog` containing whatever comes after the `/` in value. So for URL `example.com/product1/changelog/5` you would have a query variable named `changelog` with the value `5`.

If there is nothing after endpoint then variable will be present, but contain empty string. Note that `get_query_var()` won't work for such use since it is hardcoded to return empty string if query var is not set at all.

It may be enough to simply check if a variable is present and if so, modify the query variables in the query hooks (such as `pre_get_posts`) and load your own sub-post with the changelog template.

You may also want to experiment with different permalink endpoint masks, e.g. `EP_PAGES`

References:

- [Codex > Rewrite API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API) and [Codex > Rewrite API > add_rewrite_endpoint()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint)
- [Rewrite enpoints API post](http://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2012/06/07/rewrite-endpoints-api/) by Jon cave
- [Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) plugin for rewrite debug
- [Custom Post Type Permalinks post](http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/custom-post-type-permalinks) by ShibaShake (scroll down)

Comment: Got it working with add_rewrite_endpoint, thanks for the links :)

Comment: You used `EP_NONE` while I've seen other sources use `EP_PERMALINK`, could you please expand on choice of constant?