# custom data in url

Tags: php, permalinks

Inside a WordPress site I load a external xml file parse it and show some links.
The link looks like this:
`domain.com/prof/vac/item?guid=1234&title=foo`
This works, but now i would like the url to look like this:
`domain.com/prof/vac/item/1234-bar`
when I create a link to that url and click it it says it kind find the page.
However if i just put the guid in and forget about the title it works:
`domain.com/prof/vac/item/1234`

can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: is the url always prof/vac ? I assume prof and vac are pages and vac has a unique page template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the details here in this answer to solve your problem :

[Pretty URL with add_query_var](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31821/pretty-url-with-add-query-var/32117#32117)

Something along the lines of

```
add_rewrite_endpoint('item', array(EP_PAGES));
```

resulting in a rewrite rule that would let you use /prof/vac/item/1234 which you would then check in the vac pages template for a query variable 'item' and pull its value ( in this case 1234 )

Of course one must then avoid having a page with the slug 'item' else bad things will happen.